# Connecting AD to multiple networks. Use firewall rule or dual NIC?

Tags: networking, active-directory

We want to connect our AD to multiple networks. There is a firewall between these networks. I wanted to find out if it is best practice for us to open up a firewall rule for the DNS/AD or to connect to each network separately by having two NICs in the AD server?

Thanks

Comment: Not only is multi homing a bad idea but putting a firewall between a DC and clients is also bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making changes to the firewall is probably the correctest answer.

Multi-homing a DC is always problematic, and IIRC not support by Microsoft.

Comment: I can't imagine any scenario where trying to multi-home a DC is likely to result in less pain than a hoof in the gentlemen's vegetables. At least the latter pain will probably go away faster.

Comment: I had one, where I was using a DC as an image server which was supporting three different lab networks.  I was basically using the DC as a router in addition to it's normal duties.  In hindsight probably wasn't the best solution, but given the environment at the time it was the best we could do.

Answer (score 0):

Change the firewall to a router (or add a router).